# Using switch_to() in Python for a Security Warning Dialogue Box

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, security-warning

Im getting a 'security warning' popup box in Firefox.

Im using Python and Selenium

```
driver.switch_to().alert().accept()

TypeError: 'SwitchTo' object is not callable
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct syntax:

```py
driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

Or:

```py
driver.switch_to_alert().accept()
```

Or:

```
Alert(driver).accept()
```